# Communication between two Kotlin files

Tags: file, kotlin

I have two question:

1. What is the use of file(remember file not class) in kotlin since we already have classes?
2. Can we communicate between two kotlin files. If yes then how?

Comment: a. define top-level values or functions for example. b. Where you define your functions or class doesn't matter. What matters is their package, and whether or not you import them. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-code-organization

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean files ending in .kt that aren't classes, kotlin allows you to have variables and functions in the 'Global Scope' too in addition to classes. Files can access non private variables, functions, classes, etc. in other files in the same package without requiring any additional steps, but will need import statements to access files in different packages.

someText defined in File0.kt

```
const val someText = "asdf"
```

printSomeText function defined in File1.kt

```
fun printSomeText(){
    print(someText)
}
```